# What order should I do things in to move?

Tags: visa, working-visas, working, housing

My situation: I am 31 years old. I live in the UK and have been a software developer for 5 years (but only 1 year in a really challenging, full stack position). I own a house. I have a fair amount of savings and a decent salary.

However, I became divorced about a year ago. I have always wanted to move abroad, but haven't been able to as my ex-partner didn't want to.

Now I can, but I'm very apprehensive. I have a good job, am secure financially and am a home owner. I would be giving all of that up for the unknown... but it is something I've always dreamed of.

My question, is ***what order should I do things in to move***? I would not want to rent my house out,as the rent to mortgage ratio is not good where I am and the tenants in my area are notoriously bad, so if I move I will be selling.

In terms of location, my current preference is New Zealand, but I have also looked at some other places that are good for software devs (Switzerland, Canada).

So I need to sell the house, get a job, find accommodation somewhere else, ship all my belongings, set up a new bank account, get a working or residency visa. It's quite overwhelming and I'm not sure where to start or what to do first (do I move and then look for a job or get a job offer first, in which case I have to hope the house sells quickly... etc.)

Apologies for the long post, but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Except for personal and sentimental items, I'd sell rather than "*ship all my belongings*".  Otherwise you might spend a lot of money shipping things that will most likely not fit nearly as well in your new home and end up being sold anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What order should I do things in? (Moving country)](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/what-order-should-i-do-things-in-moving-country)